# Drawing on a background image

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdfpages

I'd like to take pages of an existing PDF (which are simply images), and draw several boxes on each page. (The bounding boxes of words as detected by an external OCR program.)

What I've tried so far:

- can use `\includepdf` (from the `pdfpages` package) with option `[fitpaper=true]` to make pages of the resulting PDF same as those of the original PDF.
- can use TikZ to draw rectangles/polygons, with coordinates specified using `current page.north west` and some arithmetic (which I got from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/432434/draw-rectangle-on-absolute-coordinates/432436#432436)), though there are multiple problems:

  1. They end up on a separate page,
  2. This separate page has the default (letter/A4) TeX dimensions, not those of the included PDF (though this can be set explicitly)

Here's what I have so far (using `example-image-a` instead of my PDF file):

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\paperwidth=319.999bp
\paperheight=239.999bp
\pagewidth=319.999bp
\pageheight=239.999bp
\begin{document}
\includepdf[fitpaper=true]{example-image-a}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw [line width=1mm,opacity=.25] (current page.center) circle (3cm);
\draw[red, thick] ($(current page.north west)+(102 bp,-72 bp)$) -- ($(current page.north west)+(132 bp,-72 bp)$) -- ($(current page.north west)+(132 bp,-90 bp)$) -- ($(current page.north west)+(102 bp,-90 bp)$) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

Results in two pages (in the other order if I put the `\includepdf` later):

[image]

Comment: It is wellknown that `\includepdf` inserts a full page and then switches to the next page. If you put your tikz code into a macro, then use can use the `pagecommand` or `pictuercommand` options for `\includepdf` to execute this code on the same page as the included PDF. I've used this several times to remove headers and foters when PhD students want to include PDF versions of their published articles in their dissertations.

Comment: Perhaps one of the answers at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15314/how-can-i-superimpose-latex-tex-output-over-a-pdf-file will help. Naturally, I prefer my own answer to that question :)

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/398584/image-with-some-overlaid-text

Answer (score 2):

Using `eso-pic`'s `\AddToShipoutPictureFG*` one can achieve this (I got undefined control sequence errors on `\pagewidth` and `\pageheight` and commented them):

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\paperwidth=319.999bp
\paperheight=239.999bp
%\pagewidth=319.999bp
%\pageheight=239.999bp
\begin{document}
\AddToShipoutPictureFG*{%
  \put(0,0){\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw [line width=1mm,opacity=.25] (current page.center) circle (3cm);
\draw[red, thick] ($(current page.north west)+(102 bp,-72 bp)$) -- ($(current page.north west)+(132 bp,-72 bp)$) -- ($(current page.north west)+(132 bp,-90 bp)$) -- ($(current page.north west)+(102 bp,-90 bp)$) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}%
}}%
\includepdf[fitpaper=true]{example-image-a}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! `\pagewidth` and `\pageheight` are LuaTeX's names for what are called `\pdfpagewidth` and `\pdfpageheight` in pdfTeX and XeTeX.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR ah, thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Use option `picturecommand` of `\includepdf` and put your `tikzpicture`-stuff in there:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}

\begin{document}
\includepdf[
  fitpaper=true,
  picturecommand={%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
      \draw [line width=1mm,opacity=.25] (current page.center) circle (3cm);
      \draw[red, thick]
        ($(current page.north west)+(102 bp,-72 bp)$) --
        ($(current page.north west)+(132 bp,-72 bp)$) --
        ($(current page.north west)+(132 bp,-90 bp)$) --
        ($(current page.north west)+(102 bp,-90 bp)$) -- cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}}
]{example-image-a}
\end{document}
```

Note that `picturecommand` itself uses `\AddToShipoutPicture` from the `eso-pic` package, thus this is exactly the right place where to put your drawing stuff.

Comment: Thanks, `pagecommand` works too, as mentioned by @daleif in a comment on the question.

Comment: Yes it works, but I recommend using `picturecommand` though. `pagecommand` is a very old interface used to plug in things like `\thispagestyle{empty}`, but `picturecommand` is the better place to plug in 'visible' material.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9562/46023) method:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[
fitpaper=true,
picturecommand={%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,
x={(current page.south east)},y={(current page.north west)}
]
% Help CoSy
\draw[help lines,xstep=.1,ystep=.1] (0,0) grid (1,1);
\foreach \x in {0,1,...,9} { \node [anchor=south] at (\x/10,0) {0.\x}; }
\foreach \y in {1,...,9} { \node [anchor=west] at (0,\y/10) {0.\y}; }
% Stuff
\draw[red, thick, rounded corners] (0.1,0.9) rectangle (0.25,0.75);
\draw [cyan, very thick] (0.5,0.5) circle[radius=2cm];
\draw[yellow, line width=4mm, ->] (0.7,0.1) -- (0.9,0.3);
\draw [blue, very thick] (current page.center) circle[radius=3cm];
\end{tikzpicture}}
]{example-image-a.pdf}
\end{document}
```